# How to use Microsoft PowerToys PowerRenamer tool to strip all characters after the 2nd dash?

Tags: windows-10, powertoys

I have a set of text as follows:

```
New York - Chicago - Goodbye
New York - Alaska - Hello
New York - Montana - A new beginning
```

How would I rename using power rename to remove all the text including the " - " but only the 2nd part, so it would be:

```
New York - Chicago
New York - Alaska
New York - Montana
```

Comment: I haven;t found good reference materials for regex in PowerRename, but you could try to search for `^(.+? - .+?) - .*$` and replace by `$1`.

Comment: @harrymc - thank you! that has worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found good reference materials for regex in PowerRename,
but this worked for the poster:

- Search for `^(.+? - .+?) - .*$`
- Replace by `$1`.